# onclick javascript send value to another control

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, user-controls

I would like to send value from EmployeeName to a sharepoint text filter control but the entire page freezes up when I use the following code

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="EmployeeName">
        Type Employee Name</label>
    <input id="EmployeeName">   
    <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="javascript:moveValue()" id="btnSearch" name="btnSearch" /> 
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    function moveValue() {
    var searchTXT = document.getElementById("EmployeeName").value;
    document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_ae01f1bd_e6a3_4044_8045_ab8b29c41f89_SPTextSlicerValueTextControl").value = SearchTXT;
    }
<script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a couple of things that you can do to improve your snippet.

To start the `onclick=""` syntax does not need `javascript:` part, you use `javascript:` only inside anchor tag hrefs, so that would change to

```
<input type="button" value="OK" onclick="moveValue()" id="btnSearch" name="btnSearch"/>
```

Secondly your `<input id="EmployeeName">` should have a type specified and probably a value (I don't know if you omitted it for the purpose of the example)

e.g.

```
<input id="EmployeeName" type="hidden" value="John Smith" />
```

Lastly your function `moveValue` is susceptible to null reference exceptions.

I would change it to:

```
function moveValue() {
   var employeeField = document.getElementById("EmployeeName");
   var otherControl = document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_ae01f1bd_e6a3_4044_8045_ab8b29c41f89_SPTextSlicerValueTextControl");
   //Making sure both fields are not undefined before accessing their properties.
   if(employeeField && otherControl){
      otherControl.value = employeeField.value;       
   }else{
     //Use for debugging, delete/comment once done
     alert("employeeField: " + employeeField  + ", otherControl: " + otherControl);
   }
}
```

See if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply and code. Let me test this and I will update soon. one quick question. Can I do a Postback after populating the target control.

Comment: Thank you SOOOOOOO much. worked like charm. Added this into function so the page is postback with new info from the target control. __doPostBack('<%= btnSearch.UniqueID %>','')

Comment: There is a big problem. For some reason the code is disabling all sharepoint clickable buttons or links. How to fix this?

Comment: The code above should not interfere with sharepoint buttons. I would start checking if your page generates any Javascript error (using Firebug in Firefox or Google Chrome console), any error might prevent other Javascript functions to run and stop other button's postback altogether.

Comment: You are right. SharePoint runs bunch of it's javascript. What can I do to make sure this js does not interfare with SP js? also the scroll bar went missing but if take out the js from the page (which is really a link on the page from content editor web part) then everything functions as normal